# What is the quantum state of a particle sitting at rest at the minimum of its classical potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, ground-state

Suppose a particle, moving in a potential $V(x)$, is known to be at rest, at one of the local minima of its classical potential. Therefore, classically its total energy is at its local minimum. Given this information, can we say anything about the wavefunction of the particle if we are to describe it quantum mechanically? In particular, can we say that the particle is in its quantum mechanical ground state of its Hamiltonian?

I have one example where the answer seems to be 'yes'. Consider a 1D harmonic oscillator. If the particle is at a local minimum of its classical Hamiltonian, $$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2,$$ its energy is minimum (numerically equal to zero). Since the Hamiltonian is a sum of quadratic terms, we can also infer $x=0=p=0$ and also $x^n=0=p^n=0$, etc for any psoitive integer $n$. Quantum mechanically, if we identify $x$ with $\langle\hat{x}\rangle$, $p$ with $\langle\hat{p}\rangle$, $x^n$ with $\langle\hat{x}^n\rangle$, $p^n$ with $\langle\hat{p}^n\rangle$
and so on, I think we can conclusively say that the particle is in its quantum ground state $|0\rangle$ because all the expectation values $\langle\hat{x}\rangle$, $\langle\hat{p}\rangle$, $\langle\hat{x}^n\rangle$, $\langle\hat{p}^n\rangle$, $\langle H\rangle$, etc either vanish or at least, vanish in the limit $\hbar\to 0$.

However, I am not sure if this is true in general. So I'm asking a reverse question! Knowing a few of the values of classical observables, and identifying those with the quantum expectation values of the correspponding Hermitian operators in a pure state, can we say something about the quantum wavefunction?

Comment: Basically every quantum theory introductory textbook would mention the QHO approximation of any classical particle trapped in a local minima.

Comment: Since $x^2\ge 0$ for any $x$, it cannot be that $x^2=0$ as you suggest, unless you imply that $\langle x^2\rangle=\langle x\rangle^2$, which is not the usual definition.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I meant that if classically x is known to be equal to zero, then classically all positive powers of $x$ are also zero.

Comment: yeah but since $x^2\ge 0$ there is no way $\langle x^2\rangle=0$ even if $\langle x\rangle=0$.  Indeed $\langle x^2\rangle\ne 0$ in the quantum h.o. ground state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle states that the more accurately you know the position of a particle the less accurately you know it's position. This means we can never ask for the wavefunction of a particle "at rest at a given position" as this requires us to know both the position and momentum exactly.

Since the question you have asked cannot be answered, to move forward from here, therefore, we need to ask a better question. So what are you really interesed in knowing

- What does a state of definite position or momentum look like?
- What does the state that minimises the particles total energy look like? This it turns out will minimize neither the kinetic or potential energy but will be some trade off between the two.
- Or are you actually interested in how does quantum mechanics describe the classical system you described, which it must be able to do at least approximately. So how do you take the classical limit of a quantum system and arrive at a particle at rest at a potential minimum?
- Or are you interested in something else?

Comment: So let me rephrase it like this. Suppose a pendulum hangs undisturbed in its equilibrium position. From this can we approximately deduce ints quantum mechanical wavefunction? Is it the quantum mechanical ground state wavefunction?

Comment: If you want to learn about quantum effects in macroscopic objects, read about the suspension of LIGO's mirrors.

Comment: There's no wave function strictly speaking because if the velocity or the momentum of a particle is well-known, the position creates a wavy behavior only if the mass is small enough. Every macroscopic object with a considerable mass has then a well defined position and momemtum and sit at the bottom of the potential compared to a very light particle which has a QM behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The harmonic oscillator has Hermite functions, $\psi_n(x)$, as eigenvalues with energy $\hbar\omega(n+\frac 1 2)$. The classical minimum is:

$$ \psi(x) \propto \delta(x) $$

You can expand that into a sum over all $\psi_n(x)$, and the excpectation value of the energy will be infinity.